# jQuery Collapse/expand indication, switch HTML entities accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I toggle between HTML entities & #9660 ; (downward pointing triangle) and & #9664 ; (left pointing triangle) for open and closed states, respectively, to display beside the h2-enclosed content (within a span element floated right), with the jQuery Collapse script: https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Collapse ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add javascript to the open/close functions that can be defined for each collapsable element. I modified the following demo from the download file to be the following:

HTML (added in spans with arrows):

```
<div class="col c2">
  <!-- BEGIN Custom open and close -->
  <h2>Custom show &amp; hide</h2>
  <div id="custom-show-hide-example">
    <h3><span>&#9660;</span>Hello</h3>
    <div>
      <p>Hello Sir.</p>
      <p>I'm sliding</p>
    </div>
    <h3><span>&#9660;</span>Anarachy in the UK</h3>
    <div>I like tea</div>
    <h3><span>&#9660;</span>Indeed</h3>
    <div>This is some information</div>
  </div>
```

Javascript (added function `.html()` to change the html of the affected span):

```
    new jQueryCollapse($("#custom-show-hide-example"), {
      open: function() {
        this.slideDown(150);
        $('#custom-show-hide-example h3 span').html('&#9664;'); /*my added line*/
      },
      close: function() {
        this.slideUp(150);
        $('#custom-show-hide-example h3 span').html('&#9660;'); /*my added line*/
      }
    });
```

Comment: You know what, that worked, thank you very much. Anyone happen to know how I can make the span within the header include the functionality of toggling the content on click as does the header text outside of the span? The arrow is clickable, like it's visually turned into a link as it is inside the h2 element which becomes a link, but clicking it doesn't do anything.